# How to get the sum of a list of integer dicts

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts that I have scraped from google scholar that looks something like this,

```
WRT_Citations = {Citations: 201, year: 2008, Title: Something, Author: Authors, Url: Url} {Citations: 108, year: 2006, Title: Something, Author: Authors, Url: Url}{Citations: 100, year: 2009, Title: Something, Author: Authors, Url: Url}
```

I put it in this for loop to make it more ordered.

```
    for Citations in Wrt_Citations:
        print "Print Citations ", Citations
```

which gives a more ordered list,

```
 output = {Citations: 201, year: 2008, Title: Something, Author: Authors, Url: Url}
{Citations: 108, year: 2006, Title: Something, Author: Authors, Url: Url} 
{Citations: 100, year: 2009, Title: Something, Author: Authors, Url: Url}
```

I want to get the total citations i.e 201 + 108 + 100 = 409. I have been able to get the Citations individually by doing,

```
Cites = dict.values(Citations)[0]
print cites = 201
              108
              100
```

So I tried using sum(dict.values(Citations)[0]), to get the total citations but that just give the TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.

Any help would be gladly excepted, I have been teaching my self, by tril and error python the last few weeks so some of the terms my not be correct sorry in advance, oh the list has been sorte twice and the duplicate removed also just so you know.

Comment: `Citations.values()[0]` would be more to the point.. Or better yet, `Citations['Citations']` and access the value by key.

Comment: Note that your sample code in your post is invalid Python; your list is missing the `[...]` brackets, your keys have no quoting, etc. Please do take the time to post something we can all run in our local Python copies, that makes it much easier to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a generator expression to loop over all your citation dictionaries:

```
sum(d['Citations'] for d in WRT_Citations)
```

Note that using `dict.values(Citations)[0]` is a very round-about way of saying `Citations.values()[0]`, which is an incorrect and unreliable way of saying `Citations['Citations']` (access the value associated with the `'Citations'` key in a dictionary referenced by the name `Citations`).

Answer (score 2):

Your code structure and syntax are very wrong, but assuming they were correct (as below) this is how you would do what you want:

```
WRT_Citations = [
    {'Citations': 201, 'year': 2008, 'Title': 'Something', 'Author': 'Authors', 'Url': 'Url'},
    {'Citations': 108, 'year': 2006, 'Title': 'Something', 'Author': 'Authors', 'Url': 'Url'},
    {'Citations': 100, 'year': 2009, 'Title': 'Something', 'Author': 'Authors', 'Url': 'Url'}]

total_citations = sum(d['Citations'] for d in WRT_Citations)
# 409
```

Comment: Sorry about the bad structure, First post on Stackoverflow so not quite sure of the format, Thanks that worked great :)